# Zorin Ultimate: How to obtain source code?

Tags: licenses, zorin

Zorin Ultimate is behind a paywall (https://zorinos.com/ultimate/). I understand that it's GPL license doesn't stipulate that it provide free (as in cost, not freedom to distribute/change) compiled versions of all the software it is using from the Debian fork, but I do believe source files for Ultimate have to be provided.

Does anyone know how to acquire these?

Comment: It's on the website, hidden away under the 'About' page: https://zorinos.com/about/#source-code

Comment: @Haxiel - Thanks! However, perhaps I am missing something... Does one have to use the list I have seen around of what is included in the various Zorin versions to work out what packages need to be downloaded and compiled to get a specific version of Zorin? P.S Why is the above not an answer I can accept and I & others can upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is linked to on the Zorin OS website, but it is tucked away under the 'Company' > 'About' section accessible from the site's footer. Here is the link to it: https://zorinos.com/about/#source-code

For building the OS yourself, you will need to identify the packages that you want to include. DistroWatch has a [list of the packages and their corresponding versions](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=zorin) included in each release of the OS. You could use this information and the source code repositories to work out which packages and which versions are neeeded.

I have very little experience regarding the actual build process. A resource such as [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) may be useful as a starting point. Since Zorin OS is based on Ubuntu, you may be starting from a known, pre-built version of Ubuntu and then adding/modifying packages as necessary.

In any practical scenario, you will also need to work out some way to include updates and patches from the upstream repositories into your build. The build process will also require automation, so that you can produce builds in a repeatable manner while being able to integrate changes.

Comment: Thanks for converting the comment into an answer Haxiel, and adding more info to it. I can't seem to find the packages that come with the lite, core, educational, and ultimate versions on the link your provided however. Might you have just meant 12, 14, 15, etc, and not the versions aforementioned that I was thinking of in my reply comment to my question?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the release version rather than the editions. There's [a comparison chart on the Zorin site](https://zorinos.com/download/#compare) that briefly shows the differences. Details on the packages could possibly be available from the package management system (an online repo or some sort of configuration file). I'm from the RHEL side of Linux, so I'm not very familiar with how Ubuntu manages packages.